# VirtueMart & Joomla Checkout Issues

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I have a Virtuemart store (ver: 1.1.9) running on Joomla version 1.5.6

When I try to check out, I get the cart just fine, shows correct items, then upon clicking checkout, the next page contains only a heading and a button, no main content. I can't figure it out. The result is I can't complete the Sale Transaction, as clicking the next button doesn't do anything. I'm assuming because whatever is supposed to be in the body isn't completed yet. Any help or ideas would be fantastic!

The site is fsrmotorsports.com if you're interested in seeing it.

[image: In the Popup]

[image: Not in the Popup]

Thanks!

Edit: I will say, at one point this worked just fine in this theme. I have completed an Order through this system when I first installed it, so it's got to be a VM configuration issue or something with the products configuration. As the order I completed was with Sample Data I installed Originally.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the checkout order code in the config file (administrator/components/com_virtuemart/virtuemart.cfg.php) had become corrupt.

Replacing it with the defaults fixed the issue.

```
// Checkout Steps and their order
global $VM_CHECKOUT_MODULES;
$VM_CHECKOUT_MODULES = array('CHECK_OUT_GET_SHIPPING_ADDR' => array('order' => 1,'enabled'=>1),
        'CHECK_OUT_GET_SHIPPING_METHOD' => array('order' => 2,'enabled'=>1),
        'CHECK_OUT_GET_PAYMENT_METHOD' => array('order' => 3,'enabled'=>1),
        'CHECK_OUT_GET_FINAL_CONFIRMATION' => array('order' => 4,'enabled'=>1)
    );
```